# What does the high point mean

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the term **high point** mean?

> Social insects represent the high point of invertebrate evolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High point means it's at it's peak, or it's best point in time.

> I was at my high point during the summer golf season

Means that I was doing my best, or achieving the highest during the summer time.

In your example, it means that in the evolution cycle, it was **the best it can be** or **the best to date**. Meaning social insects represent the **best/pinnacle/maximum/gretest point of invertebrate evolution.**

Comment: Or, in the context of the OP's example, "the best it can be" or "the best to date."  Thus, social insetcts represent the best/pinnacle/maximum/greatest of invertebrate evolution.

Comment: Good way to phrase it, mind if I add it to the answer?